# how to print axis2 service soapenvelope

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I'm calling one `WebService` using `axis2` client in that I added header using `OMElement`.
while executing i'm getting exception. I just want to print and check the entire `SoapEnvelope` of the request.

Please suggest me how to print the `SoapEnvelope` of request.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the tcp/ip monitor in eclipse

For example if your end point is `http://localhost:8080/Pojo/services/AddressBookService`

In Eclipse navigate to Window --> Preferences --> TCP/IP Monitor 
Click Add 
Add the local monitoring port and provide your endpoint server host & port number 
Check the option to start automatically and click ok

[image]

In Eclipse, navigate to window --> show view --> tcp/ip

[image]

Next you need to point the end point to the new port the TCP monitor is listening to

```
http://localhost:10080/Pojo/services/AddressBookService
```

Once you invoke the service you can view the SOAP Request and Response. If you have header content you can view that too.

[image]